# Custom parameter page for BIRT report

Tags: birt

Can I create a custom parameter page for BIRT Report? My users in ihub portal want to see the custom parameter page when they run the report instead of the default parameter page.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: As your question is some what unclear still I hope this may help you ...https://balendra15.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/how-to-build-a-custom-parameter-page-for-birt-report/